# both hot and neutral lines have electricity

Tags: electrical, wiring

I live in an old house built in 1960s in the US. A year ago, I hired electrician to upgrade main panel but did not re-wire existing 2-prong outlets. A few weeks ago, multiple of these 2-prong outlets stopped working while rest in the same breaker continue to work. The breaker never tripped. I had 2 electricians come out and I am not sure which one to hire or if their diagnosis is correct.

Electrician A tried to find the first outlet that works and is connected right before the broken one but couldn't find it easily. He said there is small amount of voltage running in the broken outlets. He said because my outlet boxes are very old and using crimp connectors and overtime it can cause loss connection, he believes there is 80% chance replacing all non-working outlet boxes and using wire nut could fix the issue. If this doesn't fix the issue, he would try re-wiring the next.

Electrician B said he would have to trace the line and do troubleshoot but he didn't say anything about possible loss connection. He said both hot and neutral lines are carrying electricity when nothing is plugged in and unplugged a small device I had plugged in because it is not safe to keep it plugged in.

My question is,

1. What could cause both hot and neutral to have electricity when nothing is plugged in? Quick search here shows wires could be touching each other? But wouldn't that trip the breaker?
2. Would you hire A or B? Never worked with A and I may not have working outlets after replacing them if the issue is not in outlet but in wire somewhere. But his explanation kinda make sense because no electrical work was done on my house when this happened. I've hired B for other jobs before but found him to charge 2x the average price and his work has been ok-ish.

Comment: You probably have a broken neutral somewhere between the panel and the 1st non-working outlet, and you might still have something plugged in to the non-working part of the circuit and that thing is what's making the broken part of the neutral appear to be hot. My top suspects would be either the last working outlet or the 1st non-working outlet in the circuit where there's probably a loose or broken neutral wire.

Comment: I'd suggest calling electricians C and D for their input and quotes, too. Go with the consensus opinion of those with boots on the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a third opinion and price?

Replacing all affected outlets won't help if the problem is in the previous box, so I'd guess it as closer to 50%.

There are devices for tracing wires through walls, basically by putting a signal into the wire and then scanning for it. Apparently A doesn't have one; dunno about B. I've been tempted to get one and donate it to my local library's borrowable-tools collection; they're useful in exactly this situation. (I used one to find where a contractor had cut through a wire after their own folks, including their electrician, had no clue how to proceed.)

Comment: what is that device type called?

Comment: found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k90ejXHl52I

Comment: I’m sure the Klein is good; Fluke also makes a toner in the same price ballpark.

Comment: Indeed, I'd trust either Klein or Fluke.

Comment: I need to get one, or something similar, for finding breaks in other kinds of cable...